# requestLocationUpdates() in LocationUpdate service gives null pointer error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-location, google-location-services

App crashes onstart with a null pointer exception. this happens when location permission is already granted. However doesnt occur when the location permission is not granted and only given after the app starts.

```
public void requestLocationUpdates() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Requesting location updates");
    Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
LocationUpdatesService.class));
    try {
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
        Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, false);
        Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not request updates. " + 
unlikely);
    }
}
```

Below is the error.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.projectu/com.example.projectu.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
com.example.projectu.LocationUpdatesService.requestLocationUpdates()' on a 
null object reference
    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
method 'void 
com.example.projectu.LocationUpdatesService.requestLocationUpdates()' on a 
null object reference
    at com.example.projectu.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:265)
    at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7029)
    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
```

Comment: Where did you initialize your `mFusedLocationClient`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: are you trying to access location updates in background service?

Comment: yes i am trying to access location  updates in background service

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialized mFusedLocationClient, and calling its   mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates on null object

Comment: i am using background service for location updates. it works when the permission is granted once the app has started. however when the permission is already provide prior to start the app crashes.

Comment: please refer this link. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatesforegroundservice

Comment: @Neha Did you solve the issue. If yes, can you please take a look at this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64459556/app-crashes-starting-locationupdatesservice-requestlocationupdates